# MySQL, UPDATE one Table Joining Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to update one table from another that isn´t directly connected, through another table and the statement executes correctly, but it doesn't work because it's updating without data.

The query is:

```
UPDATE cities
INNER JOIN footprints ON cities.ID=footprints.ID 
INNER JOIN (SELECT code,id_code,sum(price) AS price FROM buildings GROUP BY code,id_code) AS SUM_Price ON footprints.code=SUM_Price.code AND footprints.id_code=SUM_Price.id_code
SET cities.Total_Price=SUM_Price.price
```

Add some sample data as example.

[Example of Data tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaYHg.png)

Does anyone know what is happening?

Thanks for your support!

Comment: Are you sure the first join is correct? I suspect it should be `ON cities.ID = footprints.id_city`

Comment: I'm sure Nik. ID is the name of footprints specific field which matches with ID from cities. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Add some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: How does the statement "execute correctly" but it doesn't update? Does it mean if you turn the `UPDATE` statement to `SELECT` you'll get the desired data you want for the update? Or does it mean that the statement doesn't produce any error when executed?

Comment: @tcadidot0 That's right, I mean it doesn't produce any errors in execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must join `footprints` to `buildings` and aggregate and then join to `cities`:

```
UPDATE cities c
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT f.id, sum(b.price) price
  FROM footprints f INNER JOIN buildings b 
  ON f.code = b.code AND f.id_code = b.id_code
  GROUP BY f.id
) s ON s.id = c.id
SET c.total_price = s.price
```

Comment: Thanks, that's works! It was a problem with join order how can i see... Lot of thanks!!